# Pull all parent records with or without child record - if child record exists select latest record

Tags: mysql

I'm building a table of ALL records on vacation watch which have not expired  and are not already scheduled for a visit

- Select the property information
- Select the mapzone cars
- Select the last time the property was checked

My problem is if the property has never been checked the record is not selected

The code is:

```
FROM vacation_watch_master
LEFT JOIN property 
    ON vacation_watch_master.MstrLink = property.MstrLink
LEFT JOIN property_map_carzone 
    ON property.MapZone = property_map_carzone.MAP_ZONE
LEFT JOIN vac_watch_check_dates v1 
    ON vacation_watch_master.VWLink = v1.VWLink
WHERE v1.VWDateLink = (SELECT max(VWDateLink) 
                       FROM vac_watch_check_dates
                       WHERE vac_watch_check_dates.VWLink = vacation_watch_master.VWLink
                      )
HAVING vacation_watch_master.Watch_Expired  > -1 
   AND vacation_watch_master.MstrLink NOT IN (
                              SELECT vac_watch_schedule.MstrLink 
                              FROM vac_watch_schedule
                                             )
```

Comment: You need to have a SELECT (something) before your FROM. Your code would be much clearer if you use the ability to identify a block of code (use {} button when editing).

Comment: There may be an interesting question here, can you share table definitions, sample data and expected output? Please read through [help us help you](http://dba.blogoverflow.com/2012/06/help-us-help-you/) and [edit] your questioh

Answer (score 1):

In your `WHERE` clause, your `v1.VMDateLink = SELECT MAX(VWDateLink) ...` will not be true since the `MAX` will return `NULL`, and `NULL` is never equal to anything including `NULL`.

Try adding `OR v1.VMDateLink IS NULL`, but in general, I would create an inline view on `vac_watch_check_dates` with a single row per `VWLink` with the max `VMDateLink`.

Comment: If i add the IS NULL statement the query becomes a run-away query (Never ends)

Comment: The program returns all the data I need EXCEPT for the properties that have never had a date checked record

Comment: Are you suggesting I create a separate query of the Vacation Check table which will just contain a single record for each VWLink then access that query instead of the table?